# Why doesn't XmlSerializer work for shared class variables?

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I have the following class which I want to serialize to XML:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Settings
    Public Shared var1 As Boolean = False 
    Public var2 As Boolean = False 
End Class
```

I create a new instance and serialize it using my own method...

```
SaveSerialXML(PathToFile, New Settings, GetType(Settings))
```

...however the shared (static) variable is not included in the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <var2>false</var2>
</Settings>
```

Does anyone know of a way to serialize shared members of a class to XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization is about serializing instances. `Shared` variables do not belong to an instance.

Comment: Why is serialization about serializing instances only? That doesn't make sense. Why shouldn't serializing of a static class's properties be ok?

Comment: @steve you'd want to ask Microsoft. They might answer that it makes no sense to deserialize instances and have them overwrite the static members.

Comment: Static Members don't necessarily have static values in them. And in a settings/config situ, you might have no values at all until the app is first started. Still seems artificially narrow to me.

Comment: @SteveCinq But the value is shared across all instances.

Comment: Yes, but I only _have_ one instance (it's a settings file, in my case). And, anyway, if I want that value for all instances, my choice. And if the class is static, I may still want to serialize to/from a file. The restriction is still arbitrary, I think.

Comment: @SteveCinq So have a single instance and access it via the static property.

Comment: You mean the static property that won’t be serialised? If I’m missing something here, please post an answer. In any case, if shared properties won’t be serialised why not throw a compile error?

Comment: @SteveCinq A static property of another object, or a static member: `public static Config _theConfig = new Config();`

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat add a redirect instance property for serialization.

For example:

```
Public Property Var1Instance As Boolean
    Get
        Return Var1
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Var1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

I've often found myself wanting to implement my own Xml serialization and not use the .NET XmlSerializer.

I do so by adding an Xml property to my class that directly handles the serialization via **Xml Literals**. That property could be a `String` or an `XElement` depending on how I'm going to use it.

Here's how the Xml String property would look for your sample class:

```
Public Property Xml() As String
    Get
        Return <Settings>
                   <var1><%= var1 %></var1>
                   <var2><%= var2 %></var2>
               </Settings>.ToString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Dim xValue = XElement.Parse(value)
        var1 = xValue...<var1>.Value = "true"
        var2 = xValue...<var2>.Value = "true"
    End Set
End Property
```

This places all the serialization logic in one place and avoids the use of attributes to control how an instance gets serialized. The other benefit I've found is that this allows me to deserialize a class that does not have a default constructor.

In production scenarios I would add an extension method that converts a `String` to a `Boolean` instead of comparing to `"true"` since valid Xml Boolean values include true, false, 1 and 0.